# un downloadlabel images and videos PDF

Tags: php, security, html5-video, image-uploading

I am creating a php script for images and videos. The image and videos is uploading and displaying fine on the webpage.

I want to secure the uploaded files, means visitors can't download the files at local system.

There is any one have knowledge how we secure files.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure what you want is near impossible since if you want your visitor to view the image/video, the browser still need to download it before it can display to the end user.

if the browser can 'download' the data, pretty sure everyone can write small code to grab the data.

if you want to protect from linking to the data directly, you can prevent hot-link through htaccess (for apache) rule.

Comment: So this is impossible using PHP or any other scripting language?

Comment: unless you **completely disable viewing of the image/video**, this is really impossible thing to do. Alternatively, you can show a low resolution as preview of the data.